# Mongo db will not update an existing Document

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I am using java pojo's and spring MongoTemplate, I spent few hours now, trying to understand why MongoDb will not update an existing  Document

I am able to insert documents, but not to update existing ones

Any simple way to trace this in mongo/spring?

I tried so far:

Simply call save:

```
        person.setUpdateDate(new Date());
        mongoTemplate.save(person);
        //not working
```

call updateFirst

```
        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(person.getId())),
                                    Update.update("objName", "NotWorking"),Person.class);
```

Get the collection first, convert to DB Object,
then find and modify:

```
        DBCollection coll=mongoTemplate.getCollection("Person");
        DBObject mongoPerson = morphia.toDBObject(person);
        DBObject afterSave = coll.findAndModify(new BasicDBObject("id", person.getId()), mongoPerson);
        //afterSave is null
```

Try find by _id, then save:

```
        DBObject mongoPerson = morphia.toDBObject(person);
        Person found1 = mongoTemplate.findById(person.getId(), Person.class);
        found1.setObjName(person.getName());
        mongoTemplate.save(found1);
```

Find first, then save using "_id":

```
        DBCursor found = coll.find(new BasicDBObject("_id", person.getId()));
        DBObject first = found.next();
        mongoTemplate.save(first);
```

Find first, then save using "id":

```
        DBCursor found = coll.find(new BasicDBObject("id", person.getId()));
        DBObject first = found.next();
        mongoTemplate.save(first);
```

Try find and modify then save:

```
        DBObject afterSave = coll.findAndModify(new BasicDBObject("id", person.getId()), mongoPerson);
        //afterSave is null
        mongoTemplate.save(person);
```

Update individual fields using query:

```
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(person.getId()));
        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, new Update().set("name",person.getName())
                                                     .set("desc", person.getDesc())
                                                      .set("updateDate",new Date())
                                                          , 
                                                        Person.class)
```

Comment: how are you determining that the updates are not working?  are they getting to the server? what do they look like?  if you set logging to 1 or verbose on mongod then it will print every operation attempted in the log, success or failure.

Comment: This is what i see with profiler on: 
Tue Jul 08 22:51:32.286 [conn11] command dbName.$cmd command: { getlasterror: 1, j: true } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:85 8ms

Comment: I'm not sure what the profiler has to do with it, but getlasterror is not a write, it's the command sent after the write.  find the "update" in the logs.

Comment: asya, what command line to start mongo to enable the logs  you want?

Comment: you don't have to restart mongod - just run db.adminCommand({setParameter:1, logLevel:1}) (and when you want to set it back same with logLevel:0)

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: Wed Jul 09 14:12:07.450 [conn7] update dbName.person query: { _id: ObjectId('53b98c56ee7957044fc40667') } update: { $set: { objName: "newName" } } idhack:1 nupdated:0 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:50 0ms
Wed Jul 09 14:12:07.450 [conn7] run command dbName.$cmd { getlasterror: 1, j: true }
Wed Jul 09 14:12:07.481 [conn7] command dbName.$cmd command: { getlasterror: 1, j: true } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:85 30ms

Comment: run regular query in that database db.person.find({ _id: ObjectId('53b98c56ee7957044fc40667') })  - it looks like there was no document found to match. Which one of the above ways are you using here?

Comment: db.Person.find({ _id: ObjectId('53b98c56ee7957044fc40667') })<BR/>
"_id" : ObjectId("53b98c56ee7957044fc40667"), "className" : "com.pck.model.person", "name" : "person name", "desc" : "description here" }

Comment: I see this in the bdb profiler : ...updateDate: new Date(1404958596427) } idhack:1 nupdated:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:205 0ms

Comment: person (lower case) vs Person (mixed case).  Which one is the name of your collection?  You're trying to update "person" but you ran find on "Person" - also the last thing shows the update being applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update**
this is also working:

```
mongoOperations.save(person,"Person");
```

[Using this article](http://www.dineshonjava.com/2013/01/spring-data-mongodb-update-document.html) I was able to make update work - not the way I want, but...It works...

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where;  
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query.query;  
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update.update; 

@Controller
public class PersonController {

@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Autowired
MongoOperations  mongoOperations;

...

mongoOperations.updateFirst(query(where("_id").is(person.getId())), Update.update("name", newPersonName),"Person");
```

Not sure yet why this work while

```
mongoOperations.save(person);
```

Is not working...

Comment: ah, save without second argument will try to save to collection for the entity type of the object to save.  That entity type in your configuration is not Person. You don't actually show declaration of person variable anywhere - what's its type/class?

Comment: I'm still curious why mongoOperations.save(person) didn't work - I think if the type of person there is Person, then it should be equivalent...

Comment: if you only pass person object, where is there a place to make a mistake?

Comment: I was thinking possibly the configuration or maybe person is not of class Person - you showed your class definition, what does the declaration of person look like?  Maybe put all your code in a gist with a pointer to it - it's really hard to debug code fragments with confidence.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add db name in methods
such as:

```
    public class UserInfoService{

    public static final String INFO = "info";

    public void someMethod(UserInfo userinfo){
        mongo.save(userinfo, INFO);
    }
```

if u dont, mongo will save ur data in db with name userInfo (with capital 'I'
).